# Как добавить значение переменной в (mkdir)

Tags: php

Как добавить значение переменной  `$sot` в `mkdir`

```
mkdir('../img/user/'.$sot, 0777);
```

Comment: а переменная `$sot` инициализирована и ей задано значение?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
mkdir('../img/user/'.$sot , 0777, true);
```

Comment: спасибо за ответ, все работает.